# MOSS 2007 Document Library does not allow more than 1 item

Tags: document-library

I have a document library within a subsite which allows me to add only one item into it. When I try to add one more item I receive the following error.

> *Library can hold only one item. So please delete the existing item and upload   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object varFile, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage) 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object varFile, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage)*

The document libraries within home site and other subsites allow any number of items.
Kindly let me know how to overcome this.

Thanks.

Comment: No replies.. Is it that no one has faced this kind of an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with one of our event handlers which was actually limiting the file count to one. Deactivated it and everything worked perfectly.